# Grails Groovy 1-1 Criteria Query

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I Have 2 (simplified) classes  as below :

**Class 1:**

```
class Inventory {
 Part part  ..  
  .. and other stuff  ..  
}
```

**class 2:**

```
class Part{
  String code
  String description 
}
```

No 'owned by', 'belongs to' or anything ..

I have criteria query (overkill for this simple model but the real one is more complicated)  ..  in which I have

```
def results = Inventory.createCriteria().list(params) {

   if(searchValue) {

      or {

        part {

           ilike('code', "%${searchParam}%")
           ilike('description', "%${searchParam}%"))

      }

   }

 }
```

When I run this I get an error saying field code wasn't found ??

```
rg.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: code of: com.mypackage.Inventory..
```

What am I doing wrong ? I realize I can change this to a 'where' or something but i'm interested in why 'this doesn't work ?  Is it because I haven't defined it as 
'hasOne' or .. whatever

Thanks

Comment: It **is** because you haven't defined the relationship so GORM doesn't know how to make that into a valid Hibernate/SQL query.

Comment: So i do have to use 'hasOne' or 'belongsTo' or 'hasMany'   or  .. whatever .. Thanks very much  .. not come across it before  ..

Comment: You have a valid many to one association. Essentially your `part` closure is being ignored. I'd double check your example because it's  missing the closing bracket for the `part` closure.

Comment: Domain associations are correct. Query also seems correct except that you have an extra closing parentheses at second ilike and one missing closing braces for closure.

Comment: Sorry .. I snipped and edited the code but the gist of the code is correct .. In the 'real' code the 'part' closure is correctly delimited .. and I have the additional bracket ...